# Building a bridge to Hedera Hashgraph HBAR

Tags: nft, ada, hash

Hello Cardano community,
Does Cardano have a bridge to Hedera Hashgraph HBAR?  If not, how do I build one?  I need to be able to transfer NFTs and exchange cryptos directly avoiding intermediate cryptos routes.
Thank you,
Will W.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such bridge to my knowledge.